# Shortest Possible Delay Time

Tags: batch-file, delay

Ok, so I'm wondering as to what is all the different types of delays in CMD.
Here are some I can name:

```
SLEEP 1

ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1 > nul

choice /d y /t 1 > nul

mkdir Folder
cd Folder
tree
```

What is the shortest possible delay time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the shortest *exact* time is 10ms, with pure batch.
With checking the `%time%` variable (the resolution is 10ms).

`wmic` or other external programs have the drawback, that the time to load&start them is most often longer than the time you want to wait.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very predictable short delays you can write a small command line utility that calls [nanosleep](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timespec ts;

    // We want to sleep for 40ms
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = 40L * 1000000L; // 1ms = 1 million nanoseconds
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the utility can be made a whole lot more flexible by getting the delay from the command line.

EDIT: as pointed out by the commenters, nanosleep is not available in the standard MS compiler.  There, [sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but much more predictable then examples in question. However, I assume question is regarding MS, and nanosleep is POSIX! Anyway, this is a batch question, not programming!

Comment: @jeb I agree, but I actually see no way of getting rid of that part of uncertainty, you can just try to make the utility as tiny as possible to shorten the load time as much as possible but that's about it.

Comment: @LS_dev I agree, but [optionally windows users can still install POSIX compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix), other compilers than MS's that target Windows [support nanosleep](http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/qnx/nanosleep.html) and as a batch file is typically used to combine the activities of programs together I thought it might be worthwhile to point to this possible solution.  However, it's definitely not a universal solution.

Comment: Having in consideration that we are using scripts, I would choose standard stdlib `clock`. Universal and, anyway, high resolution can never be achieved with process loading (and scripts are not suitable environment for such).